# why this alert dialog is not working in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-alertdialog

i used below code to get alert whenever user clicks on a particular list item

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:rflutter_alert/rflutter_alert.dart';





class RamList extends StatelessWidget {



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {



    return _myListView(context);
  }
}

Widget _myListView(BuildContext context) {
  final titles = [
     'Part-1',
     'part-2',
     'part-3',
     'part-4',
     'part-5',
  ];

  final numbers = [
    '1 ',
    '2 ',
    '3 ',
    '4 ',
    '5 ',



  ];

  functionOne() {
    Navigator.push(
        context, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>  RamOne()));
  }

  functionTwo() {
    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => RamTwo()));
  }

  functionThree() {
    Navigator.push(
        context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => RamThree()));
  }

  functionFour() {
    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => RamFour()));
  }

  functionFive()=>_onAlertButtonPressed1; 





  final List<Function> onTaps = [
    functionOne,
    functionTwo,
    functionThree,
    functionFour,
    functionFive,

  ];

  return ListView.builder(

      itemCount: titles.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Card(
            elevation: 50,
            child: InkWell(



              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[


                  Container(


                    height: 100.0,
                    width:50.0,

                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        gradient:LinearGradientStyle.linearGradient(
                            orientation:LinearGradientStyle.ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL,
                            gradientType: LinearGradientStyle.GRADIENT_TYPE_AMIN
                        )
                    ),),

                  Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                      child: Text(
                        numbers[index],
                      )),


                 Flexible(child:  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    child: GradientText((titles[index]),
                      gradient:gradient,

                      style:TextStyle(fontSize:20.0,fontWeight:FontWeight.bold, ),
                    ),

                  ))
                ],
              ),
              onTap: () => onTaps[index](),
            ));
      });


}

_onAlertButtonPressed1(context) {
  Alert(
    context: context,
    type: AlertType.info,
    title: "Coming soon",
    desc: "This link will be available in future updates",

  ).show();
}
```

I tried using rflutter alert to show alert.Everything is working fine without any error.But no alert appears after clicking on destined listview..
Why this code is not working. Please help me if you have any solution..

Please comment if you need more information.By the way console message is working fine.there is no error message in the console box.

Comment: Where is __onAlertButtonPressed1_ function called?

Comment: See at the bottom part of the code

Comment: I see the definition of function, but I don't see where it is called

Comment: If you have any solution then please answer

Comment: It looks like you don't call __onAlertButtonPressed1_ function at all. I'm not sure, because maybe you just didn't show all the code. Make sure you do call the function.

Comment: It is complete code. I don't know how to call it.

Comment: It's always cumbersome to use alert dialog. The easiest way is to create a separate class for the alert dialog. You can define a universal alert dialog method in the class and use it everywhere. You can refer to this post: https://arkapp.medium.com/how-to-use-alert-dialog-in-flutter-a5637346d984

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this callback:
`functionFive()=>_onAlertButtonPressed;`

It calls __onAlertButtonPressed_, but your function that shows the dialog is called *_onAlertButtonPressed**1*** (it has 1 in the end of it).

UPD: Your callbacks should accept context and *functionFive* should call *_onAlertButtonPressed1* function:

```dart
  functionOne(BuildContext context) {
    Navigator.push(
        context, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => RamOne()));
  }

  functionTwo(BuildContext context) {
    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => RamTwo()));
  }

  functionThree(BuildContext context) {
    Navigator.push(
        context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => RamThree()));
  }

  functionFour(BuildContext context) {
    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => RamFour()));
  }

  functionFive(BuildContext context) => _onAlertButtonPressed1(context);
```

and pass the context to callbacks:

```
onTap: () => onTaps[index](context),
```

Answer (score 2):

To show an alert dialog in flutter you must do the following:

```
_onAlertButtonPressed1(context) {
         AlertDialog alert = AlertDialog(
               title: Text("Coming soon"),
               content: Text("This link will be available in future updates"),
               actions: [
                 //your actions (I.E. a button)
               ],
             );

            // show the dialog
               showDialog(
                    context: context,
                    builder: (BuildContext context) {
                    return alert;
                   },
               );
    }
```

You can view the documentation [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AlertDialog-class.html).

And an article explaining how to use an AlertDialog [here](https://medium.com/@nils.backe/flutter-alert-dialogs-9b0bb9b01d28).

Comment: This isn't the solution to problem. OP is using package to show alerts that has different API.

Comment: @ramanraman - there were double quotes in the title text, it now works